# Upsampling a time series in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-series, resampling

Let's assume a time series with `n` elements similar to this one:

```
[{value: 33209.203948532944, time: 1620178750}, 
{value: 33209.203948532944, time: 1620208647}, 
{value: 33610.0948868934, time: 1620219519}, 
{value: 34220.523450350825, time: 1620241262}, 
{value: 34220.523450350825, time: 1620242621}]
```

What is a simple algorithm in JavaScript to create another time series with `m` elements (`m` > `n`) which would have a similar visual when plotted on a chart?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't find any example of doing this in JavaScript. All the examples are using Python with Pandas.

Comment: You'll have to find a fitting curve through the given points. There are many, many different ways to define such a curve. Look for [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)). Choose one that suits you best, and then choose the x-coordinates for your new points, and calculate the corresponding y-coordinates with that spline-function.

Comment: @trincot Good point. In the mean time I've been experimenting with linear interpolation between each consecutive points, i.e., simply creating a segment between each 2 consecutive points and adding more points in-between.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far with interpolation?

Comment: @ScottSauyet please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041767/418831

Answer (score 0):

The following function uses linear interpolation between each consecutive points by simply creating a segment between each 2 consecutive points and adding more points in-between as needed. The first and last point of the series are not modified.

```
  const upSample = (series, threshold) => {
    const l = series.length;

    if (threshold <= l) { return series; }

    const sampled = [];

    // always add the first point
    sampled.push(series[0]); 

    const lerp = (x, y, a) => x * (1 - a) + y * a;

    for (var i = 1; i < threshold - 1; ++i) {
      const delta = (i / (threshold - 2)) * (l - 2);
      const left = Math.floor(delta);
      const right = Math.min(Math.ceil(delta), l - 1);
      const a = delta - left;
      const value = lerp(series[left].value, series[right].value, a);
      const time = Math.floor(lerp(series[left].time, series[right].time, a));
      sampled.push({ value, time });
    }

    // always add last point
    sampled.push(series[l - 1]); 
  
    return sampled;
  };
```

Comment: Do you have sample data and images of the results?  At a casual look, this makes sense, but sample data would help.  More importantly, though, are you satisfied with the result?  Or is the result not smooth enough and accurate enough for your purposes?